# How to split string in java

Tags: java

I have the below data in string format.

```
String value="/SOKS/
/SREF/12345-1
/PREF/23456-1
/CREF/123"
```

Expected values:

```
SOKS     setEvent("SOKS")
SREF  setRef("12345-1")
PREF  setRef1("23456-1")
CREF      setRef2("123")
```

## 2:

```
String value="/SOKS/
    /SREF/
    /PREF/23456-1
    /CREF/
```

Expected values:

```
SOKS1    setEvent("SOKS1")
SREF     setRef("")
PREF     setRef1("23456-1")
CREF     setRef2("")
```

## 3:

```
String value="/SOKS2/
    /SREF/
    /PREF/23456-1
```

Expected values:

```
SOKS2     setEvent("SOKS2")
SREF      setRef("")
PREF      setRef1("23456-1")
CREF      setRef2("")
```

I want to split the above string and set all values into a POJO.In above string /SOKS/ is dynamic, the value can be anything .

So I want to set this `value(SOKS)` in `setEvent(string)` method. For `/SREF/`(this is static) ,I want to store value 12345-1 into `setSref(string)`.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the problem? Show us some code

Comment: So what have you tried till now? Could you show us some code!

Answer (score 2):

Use String.split() method to split the strings (on /) and then retrieve the required values.
Other option is to get the substring, starting from last index of / till the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) for this.

Comment: I think you can change the link to the newer version of java. This link is for 1.4.

Comment: @JJPA I didn't noticed that. Updated the link. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 String value="/SOKS/\r\n/SREF/12345-1\r\n/PREF/23456-1\r\n/CREF/123";
String[] arr = value.split("\\r?\\n?/");
```

then:

```
setEvent(arr[1]); // SOKS

if (arr[3].equals("SREF"))
    setSref(arr[4]); // 12345-1
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/VlcNrB

Comment: Thanks.It is giving ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException error when try to access arr[8].

Comment: @RajuKomaturi: `arr[8]` will be `"123"`.

Comment: And also ,it is adding additional characters like "&#xD;" when string has \r\n

Comment: Thanks again,Problem is if any of part of string has no value,then it is giving arrayindexoutofbounds.It should work dynamically .if there is no string called SREF ,then it should work.If there is no associated value for SREF,PREF and CREF,solution should work.

Comment: It will be better if your inout string and expected values in your question.

Comment: as i said,values are not manadatory.Any of them has empty values.In this case,your solution giving ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException.How to prevent the code from these kind of situtations.

Comment: As I said `"It will be better if your inout string and expected values in your question"` so that you problem can be understood better.

Comment: Ok you will need to check for length of resulting `String[]` array and call your setters accordingly. eg. `if (arr.lrngth==8) { // logic1 } else if (arr.length==7) { // logic2 } else if (arr.length==4) { // logic3 }` etc.

Comment: is any other appoach i can do?

Comment: How your approach will work,using length?.But lengh is always same right?

Comment: No length is not always same since input string is also not always same.

Comment: hi,how this works : if (arr.lrngth==8) { // logic1 } else if (arr.length==7) { // logic2 } else if (arr.length==4) { // logic3 }  in this example , arr.length is always 8,so How else if works.Is any other good approach is there otherthan splitting array.

Comment: @RajuKomaturi: When your input is: `String value="/SOKS2/
    /SREF/
    /PREF/23456-1` then arr.length won't be 8.